# How to change uwamp apache version

Tags: apache, uwamp

I would like to use Apache 2.2.31 because that's what my live site on bluehost is running. How do I specify this version in uwamp?

I'm running uwamp on Win 10.

Answer (score 3):

change apache version in uWamp by doing like this :

Downloaded the **Apache 2.4 VC14 32bits** from [ApacheHaus](http://www.apachehaus.com/cgi-bin/download.plx).
*Select the 32bits apache version even if windows is 64bits)*

Then follow these steps:

1. Unzip the downloaded apache to UwAmp\bin directory (to obtain UwAmp\bin\apache24)
2. rename the original UwAmp\bin\apache to UwAmp\bin\apache_old
3. rename UwAmp\bin\apache24 to UwAmp\bin\apache
4. copy UwAmp\bin\apache_old\certificat to UwAmp\bin\apache\certificat
5. copy UwAmp\bin\apache_old\conf\httpd_uwamp.conf to UwAmp\bin\apache\conf\httpd_uwamp.conf
6. copy UwAmp\bin\apache_old\php.ini to UwAmp\bin\apache\php.ini
7. merge UwAmp\bin\apache_old\conf\extra with UwAmp\bin\apache\conf\extra
   (keep the newest files, just copy the old ones to the new apache dir :
   httpd-ahssl.conf, httpd-deflate.conf, httpd-proxy-html.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf)
8. That's all! Verify by starting uWamp then open localhost and look at the apache version number. Look in the uWamp log messages window for notices or errors if any.

If something went wrong just roll back to the original apache by renaming back the 2 folders:

1. close uWamp
2. rename the newest UwAmp\bin\apache to UwAmp\bin\apache_new
3. rename the original UwAmp\bin\apache_old to UwAmp\bin\apache

Comment: I'm doing the same thing (although this post is older), but I cannot locate the 4 files in UwAmp\bin\apache\conf\extra:
httpd-ahssl.conf, httpd-deflate.conf, httpd-proxy-html.conf, httpd-vhosts.conf
Would these be somewhere else?  Thanks